# How do I get rid of a "bin" folder that keeps recreating itself?

Tags: windows, java, eclipse

I've recently used Eclipse on my Windows 8 64-bit laptop. Now as far as I know, Eclipse doesn't really need to be installed - just copy-pasted.

Now, during the first use, Eclipse asks me where to put my directory and stuff. I pointed it in a folder within My Documents, just so I can consolidate all my programs into one location.

**The problem:**

After I'm done with Eclipse, I deleted it. Just like that. There wasn't anything in the Control Panel, anyway. In any case, there's a left over 'Bin' folder, that keeps coming back when I delete it.

[image: The Ghost Folder]

**What I've tried:**

Well, I've tried deleting the folder. It can be deleted, without any problems, but it comes back after a few seconds.

I've also tried deleting the entire "My Programs" folder... it just recreates it, "My Programs" folder and all.

Renaming the "My Programs" doesn't work either.

Here's what's inside the "bin" folder:

> \bin\Software\eclipse\features\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature.completion.rcp.intellig_1.0.3.v20130211-0152-b208\META-INF\maven\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature.completion.rcp.intellig
>
> \bin\Software\eclipse\features\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature.completion.rcp.subwords_1.0.3.v20130211-0152-b208\META-INF\maven\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature.completion.rcp.subwords

I haven't tried completely uninstalling Java (because I have other apps that rely on it) before deleting stuff, though.

[image: Control Panel]

I know this is just minor, but I'd like to keep my system clean, and clearly something that recreates itself is something unclean.

For the same reason, I don't want to turn to third-party "unlocker" apps.

Thanks to any and all who could help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer? It is possible that the folder is locked and you are unable to delete it. Restarting the computer will release the lock and you can delete it then.

Comment: If you replace the bin folder by a bin file, the culprit may show up.

Comment: @ADTC, yes it's been weeks since this glitch has been bugging me. I've done several restarts since then.

Comment: @mouviciel, how do I replace it with a bin file? An empty notepad file?

Comment: @zack_falcon After deleting the folder, put a file there with the exact same name as the folder (no extensions). The file content doesn't matter. What I'd do is right-click empty space **> New > Text Document**. Change the file name from `New Text Document.txt` to `bin` (NOT `bin.txt`). You can also open a _Command Prompt_ to the parent folder and enter `echo > bin`.

Comment: @ADTC, unfortunately, the Bin folder goes back as soon as I delete it. I can't place the Bin 'file'.

Comment: Try using a batch script that immediately creates the file after deleting the folder. Run the batch script as many times as needed to get the file created. Maybe even add it to the Startup folder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I think your Eclipse still use this directory. You should create new workspace for this Eclipse. If you have it, you could delete this workspace:</del>

```
Windows > Preferences > General > Startup & Shudown > Workspaces > [Remove]
```

EDIT:

I can imagine some program (for example Maven) still use this directory. When you started use Eclipse program, it was create some folder and install some dependencies to your PC. Please check these directories in your PC: `.m2`,`.eclipse`, `workplace`, `.metadata`. If you find one of them, please try to delete it.

I see you have jdk in your PC. Please check which programs run when try to delete your **bin** folder. The `eclipse` or `javax` could be use this directory.

Comment: I deleted Eclipse already, but I wasn't aware of this step. What would happen if I "re-install" Eclipse?

Comment: @zack_falcon I think If you "install" same Eclipse, you can be remove this workspace. But before that try it, please look at **Maven** in your PC. May be this use `My Programs/bin` folder.

Comment: I just got my PC back. I do not have maven on it, and I did delete the workspaces, but no dice.

Comment: I edidet my answer. I hope it helps.